# Should the helpful flags be rewarded?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Flagging is a very nice and important feature that helps to make the site clean and effective.

Should the **helpful flags** be rewarded to promote the users ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was tried, sort of.  There used to be something called Flag Weight that was similar to reputation, and some users enjoyed the "game" of trying to increase it.  It had some problems, though — it punished good flaggers disproportionately for mistakes, and complaints about rejected flags were constant.  There's still a count of helpful flags on your profile page though, and there are badges for flagging (e.g., [Marshal](https://android.stackexchange.com/badges/74/marshal)).

IMO we don't have a problem with not enough flags, so encouraging it further is unnecessary given the potential downsides.

Comment: Thanks @eldarerathis, I try to use US spellings here but forget sometimes :P

Comment: Oh, is that the typical UK/British spelling? I just saw that the badge name only has one 'L' so I assumed it was a typo. Usually I'm better with those kinds of things since I actually favour UK spellings on many words, but "Marshall" would be a new one to me.

Comment: @eldarerathis Hmm, looking it up it appears to be a minor variant. Now I'm wondering if it's the norm where I am because I certainly learned it that way :P

Comment: @MatthewRead *Is there* a helpful flag count in your profile? I tried to look at my flagging history as I can at Stack Overflow through the "helpful flags" link in the profile, but I couldn't find one. I *can* see my flagging history by directly browsing to `http://android.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/<my_user_id>`, but the link in from the profile seems to be missing. (At SO it's right under "profile views", but I couldn't find it anywhere else in my android.se profile either.)

Comment: @AdiInbar It shows for me on my profile here.  Maybe it's only shown after a certain number of flags?